# Exclude /cookie-law.xyz/0/ from Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I have been trying to filter out a bunch of old spam referrers from Google Analytics and have been successful with most, but I'm having issues with a bunch that are with the url /cookie-law.xyz/0/ thru /cookie-law.xyz/20/. I've tried a bunch of variations using regex metacharacters to no avail. Here is how it looks as a set up: [Screenshot of filter in Google Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7MQJ.png)

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

cmalexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the regex you are looking at is

```
\/cookie-law\.xyz\/\d+\/?
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Thanks! Really appreciate your help!